# Input 0 is incompatible with layer xxx (probably problem about converting keras lambda to custom class for tensorflow.js)

Tags: keras, lambda, tensorflow.js

I convert a trained h5 model to tfjs model by tensorflowjs_converter. When I use this model in nodejs, I get the error below.

```
Error: Input 0 is incompatible with layer dense: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=0.
```

Python code

```
def siamese(input_shape):
    vgg_model = VGG16()
    input_image_1 = Input(shape=input_shape)
    input_image_2 = Input(shape=input_shape)
    encoded_image_1 = vgg_model.call(input_image_1)
    encoded_image_2 = vgg_model.call(input_image_2)
    l1_distance = Lambda(lambda tensors: K.abs(tensors[0] - tensors[1]))([encoded_image_1, encoded_image_2])
    out = Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(l1_distance)
    out = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(out)

    model = Model([input_image_1, input_image_2], out)
    return model
```

There is a Lambda function in the middle and I guess it is the one that causes the error.

Since tfjs does not support lambda, I write a custom class instead.

JS code

```
class LayerAbs extends tf.layers.Layer {
    constructor() {
        super({});
        this.supportsMasking = true;
    }
          
    computeOutputShape(inputShape) {
        // inputShape is [[null, 4608], [null, 4608]]
        return [null, 4608]
    }
          
    call(inputs, kwargs) {
        if (Array.isArray(inputs)) {
            return tf.abs(inputs[0] - inputs[1])
        }
        return tf.abs(inputs)
    }
          
    static get className() {
        return 'LayerAbs';
    }
}
tf.serialization.registerClass(LayerAbs);
```

And I changed the class_name Lambda in model.json to LayerAbs

In python by calling model.predict([img1, img2]), I can get the result.
img1 and img2 have the format below

```
[
  [
    [[R,G,B],[R,G,B],...],
    [[R,G,B],[R,G,B],...],
    ...
  ]
]
```

Tfjs does not allow me to pass inputs with such format, so I call tf.tensor(data)

```
model.predict([tf.tensor(img1), tf.tensor(img2)])
```

Here img1 and img2 have the same format as above

Then I get the error.

part of model.json

```
                {
                    "class_name": "LayerAbs",
                    "config": {
                        "name": "lambda",
                        "trainable": true,
                        "dtype": "float32",
                        "function": ["4wEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAFAAAAUwAAAHMWAAAAdACgAXwAZAEZAHwAZAIZABgAoQFTACkDTukA\nAAAA6QEAAAApAtoBS9oDYWJzKQHaB3RlbnNvcnOpAHIGAAAA9TYAAABFOi9EZXZlbG9wL+a1i+iv\nlS9TaWFtZXNlLWtlcmFzLW1hc3Rlci9uZXRzL3NpYW1lc2UucHnaCDxsYW1iZGE+JAAAAHMCAAAA\nFgA=\n", null, null],
                        "function_type": "lambda",
                        "module": "nets.siamese",
                        "output_shape": null,
                        "output_shape_type": "raw",
                        "output_shape_module": null,
                        "arguments": {}
                    },
                    "name": "lambda",
                    "inbound_nodes": [
                        [
                            ["flatten", 0, 0, {}],
                            ["flatten", 1, 0, {}]
                        ]
                    ]
                }, {
                    "class_name": "Dense",
                    "config": {
                        "name": "dense",
                        "trainable": true,
                        "dtype": "float32",
                        "units": 512,
                        "activation": "relu",
                        "use_bias": true,
                        "kernel_initializer": {
                            "class_name": "GlorotUniform",
                            "config": {
                                "seed": null
                            }
                        },
                        "bias_initializer": {
                            "class_name": "Zeros",
                            "config": {}
                        },
                        "kernel_regularizer": null,
                        "bias_regularizer": null,
                        "activity_regularizer": null,
                        "kernel_constraint": null,
                        "bias_constraint": null
                    },
                    "name": "dense",
                    "inbound_nodes": [
                        [
                            ["lambda", 0, 0, {}]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
```

Appreciate anyone who can give me a tip or tell me where I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the bug.

In the js class LayerAbs, I should use tf.sub instead of writing inputs[0] - inputs[1] directly